# How can I link to the Upload Document page without using the GUID of the document library?

Tags: javascript, document-library, file-upload, url, guid

Currently I'm showing the Upload Document screen in a modal so my users can upload a document to a Document Library.

The URL I'm calling to display that modal is this:

`http://example.com/_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List={listId}`

I would really prefer to not use a `GUID` here because when migrating from `dev->testing->production` the `GUIDs` will all change (or so I understand).

Is there a way to accomplish the same thing without using the `GUID`?

How do people normally handle this issue?

The only thing I can think of is somehow querying for the List `GUID` based on its name, but this seems like overkill & I haven't been able to find a way to do it, searching yields a bunch of questions about getting the document's GUID, but I need the Document Library's.

Comment: Dynamically generate the URL by getting the List ID

Comment: How do I get the list ID?

Comment: How are you forming the link?

Comment: I have a JS function for uploading docs that takes a list GUID as a parameter and I'm just appending it to that URL. I don't want to have to pass in a hard-coded GUID when I call that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JavaScript you can get ID using

```
var list;
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Start, "sp.js");

function Start() {
    var currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    list = currentcontext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ListTitle');
    currentcontext.load(list, 'Id');
    currentcontext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, OnSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, onFailed));
}

function OnSuccess() {
    alert(list.get_id());
}

function onFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that depends a lot on how your project is structured and your deployment process.

In scenarios like this, I use feature activation code to provision my document library with a GUID generated by the Visual Studio tool. Then in my code I reference this GUID where necessary. Then once the feature is packaged, deployed, and activated, it is consistent across environments.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean as I am new to SharePoint, but thanks for giving me something to look into. I was advised that I'm not allowed to activate features and have been doing everything in JS/SharePoint Designer thus far. Not sure if that makes a difference here or not.